# How to autosave Foreignkey value inside my second Model with the id of my first model object.??

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-admin

I have two models . Appname and Adspace ,I have a Foreignkey object in second model which connects to my first model. Here is the Code

## models.py

```
 class Appname(models.Model):
      name=models.CharField(max_length=150,blank=False,null=False,help_text='Add your new App')

      def __str__(self):
          return self.name

      def get_absolute_url(self):
          return reverse("dashapp:space",kwargs={'pk':self.pk})


class Adspace(models.Model):
      ad_space=models.CharField(max_length=150,blank=False,null=False) 
      app=models.ForeignKey('Appname', related_name='appnames',default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      PID_TYPE = (
    ('FN','FORMAT_NATIVE'),
    ('FNB','FORMAT_NATIVE_BANNER'),
    ('FI','FORMAT_INTERSTITIAL'),
    ('FB','FORMAT_BANNER'),
    ('FMR','FORMAT_MEDIUM,RECT'),
    ('FRV','FORMAT_REWARDED_VIDEO'),
)
     format_type=models.CharField(max_length=3,choices=PID_TYPE,default='FN',blank=False, null=False)

     def __str__(self):
          return self.ad_space

     def get_absolute_url(self):
          return reverse("dashapp:view")
```

## modelForm

```
class AdspaceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
       model=Adspace
       fields=('ad_space',)
```

## Views.py

```
class space(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):

       form_class=forms.AdspaceForm
       model=Adspace
```

Now I.m unable to fill my form as it says it app_id cannot be null and i'm allowing user to input it. I want that the app which got clicked has its ID in the url (As I'm passing it through there).
What should i do that it gets autosave with the same id number by itself that is being passed in the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define `form_valid` in the view and set it there.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.app_id = self.kwargs["app_id"]
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: It worked! I was using def save() method , Thought i need to save the data so i should use def save() method